# Как получить список объектов окна через win32api?

Tags: python, winapi

Уточнение:
в любом приложении есть всякие меню, тулбары и пр...
каким образом можно получить список этих объектов через win32api?
дальнейшее действие - выбрать один из объектов и получить его координаты.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что помимо hwnd есть cwnd, и копать надо в эту сторону? а если приложение не на С++ написано?

Могу ли я получить доступ к координатам данных объектов?
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-implementingdock
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/uiribbon/ne-uiribbon-ui_controldock

Comment: GetWindow EnumWindows https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindow Там иерархическая структура. В окно можно вкладывать обьекты, а в обьекты можно вкладывать обьекты ещё и ещё.

Comment: cwnd - это класс-обвертка. Обьекты типа окна строятся по hwnd-дескриптору, наличие дескриптра не означает наличие cwnd.

Comment: @nick_n_a, пытаюсь реализовать на python привязку к текущему активному окну приложения, но у него есть меню (файл правка и пр), ниже тулбар, ниже которого нужно привязаться.

Comment: EnumWindows выводит только имя приложения, в нем можно создать несколько документов, но они не выводятся в списке EnumWindows, да и окон как таковых там нет. Меня интересует как вывести список всех элементов из которых состоит приложение? т.е. если приложение состоит из нескольких кнопок, то мне нужно получить кнопки, если панель с кнопками то панель, и т.д...